# Optimize with indexing in linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, cvxpy, mathprog, cvxr

I have encountered several optimization problems that involve identifying one or more *indices* in a vector that maximizes or minimizes a cost. Is there a way to identify such indices in linear programming? I'm open to solutions in `mathprog`, `CVXR`, `CVXPY`, or any other API.

For example, identifying an index is needed for change point problems (find the index at which the function changes), putting distance constraints on the traveling salesman problem (visit city X before cumulative distance Y).

As a simple example, suppose we want to identify the location in a vector where the sum on either side is the most equal (their difference is smallest). In this example, the solution is index 5:

```r
x = c(1, 3, 6, 4, 7, 9, 6, 2, 3)
```

## Attempt 1

Using `CVXR`, I tried declaring `split_index` and using that as an index (e.g., `x[1:split]`):

```r
library(CVXR)
split_index = Variable(1, integer = TRUE)
objective = Minimize(abs(sum(x[1:split_index]) - sum(x[(split_index+1):length(x)])))
result = solve(objective)
```

It errs `1:split_index` with `NA/NaN argument`.

## Attempt 2

Declare an explicit index-vector (`indices`) and do an elementwise logical test whether `split_index <= indices`. Then element-wise-multiply that binary vector with `x` to select one or the other side of the split:

```r
indices = seq_along(x)
split_index = Variable(1, integer = TRUE)
is_first = split_index <= indices
objective = Minimize(abs(sum(x * is_first) - sum(x * !is_first)))
result = solve(objective)
```

It errs in `x * is_first` with `non-numeric argument to binary operator`. I suspect that this error arises because `is_first` is now an `IneqConstraint` object.

Comment: No, that is all incorrect. CVXR does not understand the R constructs you are using. Besides, what you do would also be (very) nonlinear. You need to use binary variables. If no one else is explaining this, I will try to answer in more detail later tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Symbols in red are decision variables and symbols in blue are constants.

R code:

```r
> library(Rglpk)
> library(CVXR)
> 
> x <- c(1, 3, 6, 4, 7, 9, 6, 2, 3)
> n <- length(x)
> delta <- Variable(n, boolean=T)
> y <- Variable(2)
> order <- list()
> for (i in 2:n) {
+     order[[as.character(i)]] <- delta[i-1] <= delta[i]
+ }
> 
> 
> problem <- Problem(Minimize(abs(y[1]-y[2])),
+                    c(order,
+                      y[1] == t(1-delta) %*% x,
+                      y[2] == t(delta) %*%x))
> result <- solve(problem,solver = "GLPK", verbose=T)
GLPK Simplex Optimizer, v4.47
30 rows, 12 columns, 60 non-zeros
      0: obj =  0.000000000e+000  infeas = 4.100e+001 (2)
*     7: obj =  0.000000000e+000  infeas = 0.000e+000 (0)
*     8: obj =  0.000000000e+000  infeas = 0.000e+000 (0)
OPTIMAL SOLUTION FOUND
GLPK Integer Optimizer, v4.47
30 rows, 12 columns, 60 non-zeros
9 integer variables, none of which are binary
Integer optimization begins...
+     8: mip =     not found yet >=              -inf        (1; 0)
+     9: >>>>>  1.000000000e+000 >=  0.000000000e+000 100.0% (2; 0)
+     9: mip =  1.000000000e+000 >=     tree is empty   0.0% (0; 3)
INTEGER OPTIMAL SOLUTION FOUND
> result$getValue(delta)
      [,1]
 [1,]    0
 [2,]    0
 [3,]    0
 [4,]    0
 [5,]    0
 [6,]    1
 [7,]    1
 [8,]    1
 [9,]    1
> result$getValue(y)
     [,1]
[1,]   21
[2,]   20
>
```

The absolute value is automatically linearized by CVXR.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, if you are selecting things by index, I think you need to work this with a set of corresponding binary selection variables.  The fact that you are selecting "things in a row" as in your example problem is just something that needs to be handled with constraints on the binary variables.

To solve the problem you posed, I made a set of binary selection variables, call it `s[i]` where `i = {0, 1, 2, ..., len(x)}` and then constrained:

```
s[i] <= s[i-1] for i = {1, 2, ..., len(x)}
```

which enforces the "continuity" from the start up to the first non-selection and then thereafter.

My solution is in Python.  LMK if you'd like me to post.  The concept above, I think, is what you are asking about.