# Piecewise Linear Functions in CVXPY

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy, piecewise, convex-optimization

I have a convex optimization problem with separable, convex, piecewise linear functions f_i(var_i) each defined by a list of points [(values, costs)] and a couple other terms that are also convex.  I'm trying to figure out how two build those piecewise functions in CVXPY.

How do I take the below two lists of points and add them to a CVXPY objective as piecewise functions?

```
import cvxpy as cp
w = cp.Variable(n)

f1_points = [(-5, 10), (-2, -1), (0, 0)]  # -5 <= var1 <= 0  (Convex)
f2_points = [(-4, 5), (0, 0)]  # -4 <= var2 <= 0  (Linear)

f1_cost_function = ...
f2_cost_function = ...
constraints = [cp.sum(w) = 0] + ...
problem = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cp.sum([f1_cost_function, f2_cost_function] + ...)), constraints)
```

Comment: mmm... it may be that I can not create a piecewise function from points but instead you have to create the functions and use cp.max([f1's]).  I'll wait to see if there is a better way though.

Comment: https://cvxopt.org/userguide/modeling.html

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62432731/optimize-with-indexing-in-linear-programming. I asked this quite general question to begin working towards change point detection using linear programming. Because I wanted it to solve non-small problems (> 10^4 data points), it was impermissibly slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this does not appear directly possible in CVXPY from the list of points.  However if the piecewise functions are rewritten as point-slope functions instead of a collection of points, the cvxpy `maximum` function can be used for to make the piecewise linear function.

```
f1_functions = [f1_line1, f1_line2, ...]
f1 = cp.maximum(f1_functions)
```

This is described with an example in the [user guide](http://cvxopt.org/userguide/modeling.html).

Answer (score 1):

If your curve is simple, like in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjf2p.png), and your objective function is to minimize y, then you can do this simply by putting constraints like this:

```
contraints = [y <= f1, y <= f2, y <= f3, y <= f4 ]
objective = cp.minimize(y)
```

[Picture of simple Piece-wise functions for a non-linear curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjf2p.png)